# Conda Packages Conflict, Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, geopandas, conda-forge

I received the following error when trying to install geopandas in my environment after it failed in the terminal via the conda-forge command. Is there a way to get this updated and fixed?

````
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package geopandas-base conflicts for:
geopandas -> geopandas-base==0.9.0=py_1
geopandas-base

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.9 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
geopandas -> python -> ca-certificates```
````

Answer (score 0):

You’re installing geopandas into an existing environment with conflicting packages. This can happen when the other env has packages pinned to specific incompatible packages, or if packages have been installed from incompatible channels, e.g. if you’re installing into your base env using anaconda, or (though this happens less often these days) if it’s just been a really long time since you updated your packages.

Instead, create a new environment with the packages you need, e.g.:

```
conda create -n geopandas -c conda-forge python=3.10 geopandas gdal pygeos pandas scipy […]
```

If you’d like to delete the previous environment you can do so with

```
conda env remove -n other-env-name
```

If you continue to have issues and you’re using anaconda, I’d strongly suggest deleting anaconda, which bundles packages from the defaults channel which is incompatible with conda-forge, and install [miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#download) or it’s much faster compiled (but slightly less user friendly) cousin [mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge).

Answer (score -1):

```
$ conda install -c anaconda pip
$ pip install geopandas
```

Comment: Dont mix Conda and Pip, you'll just end up with a pair of confused package managers.