# Miniconda python UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Tags: python, centos, intel, geopandas, miniconda

I am trying to install geopandas in python with the command:
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" geopandas
(I use intel compiler for miniconda and linux centos)

But, the feedback is :

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /

Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                       failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

- feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
- feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0

Your installed version is: 2.17

I tried to install geopandas.

Finally, I recreated another environment, and the download with conda forge was suceesful.

Comment: Are you using anaconda? This can happen as a result of mixing and matching channels. I would recommend deleting anaconda and installing miniconda or better yet miniforge or mambaforge. See e.g. this post for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74174886/3888719

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem while installing geopandas with conda (anaconda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73238923/problem-while-installing-geopandas-with-conda-anaconda)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado although I am using miniconda, I have been told (in work) to install it with conda forge and miniconda. Also, strangely i had no problem using a gcc compiler instead of intel . And thank you very much for your help, as for the documentation, about miniforge and mambaforge.

Comment: Got it. Yeah I’d definitely recommend that pairing as well. The issue comes if you have any other packages in your current env from the defaults channel, which is incompatible with conda-forge. I’d try creating a clean env with all packages at once

Comment: Any reason you used `-c "conda-forge/label/cf202003"` instead of `-c conda-forge`?

Comment: I tried all of them. However, when i recreated another environment for some reason -c conda-forge was accepted.